# Tell make to rerun a target if the target is more than X hours old?

Tags: makefile

I have a simple Makefile that processes some data to produce some other data. There are many steps, which can be time consuming, hence my use of make. One of the initial steps (ie targets) is to download an input datafile from a website. However that website only updates every day. While working on the processing, I don't want to have to download the file every time (and hence do all the intermediate processing steps), however the next day, when there is a new input file, I'd like make to download that and work with that.

Is there anyway to tell make "If this file is more than X hours/etc old, then 'rebuild' it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make itself doesn't support that, so have it execute a target that checks the download date and only performs the download if the file is old.

I'll assume that you have standard Unix utilities available. If you need this on Windows, you can use one of the many ports of Linux/POSIX utilities to Windows.

If you don't care to have the date of the local file match the date on the server, you can use the file's modification time.

```
data-file:
        test -n "$$(find $@ -mtime -1)" || \
        rm $@ && \
        wget --no-use-server-timestamps http://example.com/data-file
```

If you want the local copy to match the server date, you can test the file's ctime. That can change due to other reasons (e.g. if you move the file) but it may be good enough for this use case.

```
data-file:
        test -n "$$(find $@ -ctime -1)" || \
        rm $@ && \
        wget -N http://example.com/data-file
```

An alternative approach, if you can't rely on the timestamps of the file itself, is to create a timestamp file. In dependencies, depend on `data-file.stamp` to depend on the date of the download.

```
data-file:
        test -n "$$(find $@ -mtime -1)" || \
        rm $@ && \
        wget -N http://example.com/data-file
data-file.stamp: data-file
        touch data-file.stamp
```

In addition, if the server supports it, you can tell it to feed you the file only if its copy is newer than yours.

```
data-file:
        test -n "$$(find $@ -mtime -1)" || \
        curl --remote-time --time-cond http://example.com/data-file
```

Alternatively, you could arrange not to change the local file at all if the server copy hasn't changed.

```
data-file:
        cd tmp && wget http://example.com/data-file
        if cmp -s tmp/data-file $@; then rm tmp/data-file; else mv tmp/data-file $@; fi
```

Some of these approaches can be combined.

Answer (score 1):

My strategy would be to write a rule that is always triggered and in the rule's commands skip the regeneration if the target is young enough. Exercise for the reader and all that :-)

This works because `make` considers a target up-to-date if a matching rule was executed, even if the time stamp did not change.